# How to implement Nvidia ShadowPlay like audio recording

Tags: audio-recording, android-audiorecord

So, I was always intrigued by the ShadowPlay feature by Nvidia which keeps always keeps recording and when you press a button it saves video from now to the past X number of minutes, say 15 minutes.
So, you don't miss any cool gaming moments.

I want to build a similar audio recorder for Android and was interested in the psuedo code or concept or logic of how you'd do it.

One method I can think of is save a recording every one minute plus one more minute in the past of what the user has set. Say, the user has set 15 minutes, we save a recording every one minute and delete any recording older than 16 minutes. If the user asks to save the last 15 minutes, we combine all the last 16 files and save them in a location and give it to the user. Maybe even cut the 16th file to produce an exactly 15 minute file.

I have a feeling that ShadowPlay's implementation is not as simple as this. So, I want to know if there are better ways of doing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ShadowPlay or GeForce Experience and similar Software (I think AMD has a similar feature) are permanently recording a video to a streaming format like WMV. They have a configurable buffer size, which can be for example 15 minutes.

Because it's a streaming format, all data that is older than 15 minutes will just be cut off from the beginning of the video file in a set interval. It could be every minute or every second. But the recording continues to append new video data to the end of the file synchronously.

If you hit the save button and the software is configured to save the last 5 minutes, it just cuts out the last 5 minutes of the buffer recording and saves it to the configured destination.

So for your audio recorder it's literally the same principle. Don't create new audio files every minute, use a streaming audio format like WMA. Record to a buffer and when the user hits the save button, extract the relevant part from the buffer and save it to some location on the device.

Answer (score 0):

I found a FOSS app called Echo doing the same thing I want, but the twist is instead of writing to disk, the app only stores the audio in memory until the user chooses to save the recording.

The dev claims to use memory buffer instead of writing to disk because writing to disk can drain battery life.

[Echo Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.mrogalski.saidit&hl=en_US)

[Echo Github page](https://github.com/mafik/echo)

Here are some key points related to how this app works taken from the App's description.

> 2. How does it technically work?
>
>    - it uses some memory as a cyclic recording buffer
>    - when it records it just points sound processor to write to this memory and goes to sleep
>    - when sound processor is done, it wakes, points to a next part of memory and goes to sleep again
>    - it doesn't process sound in any way - no resampling, no compression, it just keeps the recording going
>    - once you want to save recording, the memory is saved to .wav file on sdcard.
> 3. How much memory does this use?
>
>    - 1/16 of total device memory but not less than 5 minutes. It's usually
>        from 6 to 24 minutes. If you have a 2GB of RAM, it will probably store
>        around 25 minutes. You can increase this time up to three times in
>        settings.
> 4. Can it use flash memory to extend history?
>
>    - It would make cpu write to flash memory. In theory it's possible but I
>        didn't add this because it would reduce battery life.
> 5. Can it use free memory to extend history?
>
>    - On 4.0+ devices there is a way for apps to use all of free memory and
>        release it when system is under pressure. This however would interfere
>        with background apps (which usually live in unused memory) and it
>        might cause loss of recording when a memory-intensive app starts.
>        User-controlled memory usage would probably be best but clear and
>        intuitive design is a problem here.